# linux autoscaler with F/OSS

Tags: linux, autoscaling

I'd like to implement an autoscaler using Linux, something with the functionality of the AWS autoscaler -- that is, I'm not running in AWS but I'd like to have a similar device :)

Has anyone done something like this? Any ideas of where to start with open-source tools?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider something like Apache Mesos or some of its competitors/peers. It probably does more than what you want, but may fit the bill. I guess part of the question is if you are scaling at the application level or the os level. The Apache Mesos project is here: https://mesos.apache.org/

Edit...
Hashicorp focuses a lot on work in the virtualization area and have open source tooling (https://www.hashicorp.com/#open-source-tools). Likewise, you could look at Docker and similar Container technologies. They are lower level and lighter-weight than virtual machines. The tooling comes in commercial and open source varieties.

Comment: My intent was to autoscale at the virtualization level in a VM infrastructure agnostic way. That is, have VirtualBox or VMware add the new instance to the group.